# Why does using uniform initializer syntax result in different behavior to the "old" style ()?

Tags: c++, c++17, uniform-initialization

I get different results if I try to use a uniform initializer for `std::set`.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::array a {1,2,3,4};
    std::set<int> s1 {a.begin(), a.end()};
    std::set      s2 {a.begin(), a.end()};
    std::set      s3 (a.begin(), a.end());

    for(auto& i: s1) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
    std::cout << "####" << std::endl;
    for(auto& i: s2) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
    std::cout << "####" << std::endl;
    for(auto& i: s3) { std::cout << i << "\n"; }
}
```

Results in:

```
1   
2   
3   
4   
####
0x7ffecf9d12e0
0x7ffecf9d12f0
####
1   
2   
3   
4
```

This seems to be related to "deduction guides", which are evaluated differently if used with `{}` or `()` syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer

For `s2`, brace syntax is used, and `{a.begin(), a.end()}` is considered to be an `initializer_list` of `std::array<int>::iterator`s. Therefore, `s2` is a set of iterators.

For `s3`, parentheses syntax is used, and the iterator constructor is selected. `s3` is a set of `int`s, and is initialized from the range `[a.begin(), a.end())`.

## Long answer

Per [[set.overview]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/set.overview), we have two deduction guides relevant here:

> ```
> template<class InputIterator,
>          class Compare = less<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>,
>          class Allocator = allocator<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>>
>   set(InputIterator, InputIterator,
>       Compare = Compare(), Allocator = Allocator())
>     -> set<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, Compare, Allocator>;
> ```

and

> ```
> template<class Key, class Compare = less<Key>, class Allocator = allocator<Key>>
>   set(initializer_list<Key>, Compare = Compare(), Allocator = Allocator())
>     -> set<Key, Compare, Allocator>;
> ```

---

Per [[over.match.class.deduct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.class.deduct#1):

> A set of functions and function templates is formed comprising:
>
> - [...]
> - (1.4) For each *deduction-guide*, a function or function template with the following properties:
>
>   - The template parameters, if any, and function parameters are those of the *deduction-guide*.
>   - The return type is the *simple-template-id* of the *deduction-guide*.

In this case, the synthesized functions and function templates for the aforementioned deduction guides are, respectively,

```
template<class InputIterator,
         class Compare = less<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>,
         class Allocator = allocator<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>>
auto __func1(InputIterator, InputIterator,
            Compare = Compare(), Allocator = Allocator())
  -> set<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, Compare, Allocator>;
```

and

```
template<class Key, class Compare = less<Key>, class Allocator = allocator<Key>>
auto __func2(initializer_list<Key>, Compare = Compare(), Allocator = Allocator())
  -> set<Key, Compare, Allocator>;
```

(I used double underscores to signify that these names are synthesized, and are not otherwise accessible.)

---

Per [[over.match.class.deduct]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.class.deduct#2):

> Initialization and overload resolution are performed as described in
>   [dcl.init] and [over.match.ctor], [over.match.copy], or
>   [over.match.list] (as appropriate for the type of initialization
>   performed) for an object of a hypothetical class type, where the
>   selected functions and function templates are considered to be the
>   constructors of that class type for the purpose of forming an overload
>   set, and the initializer is provided by the context in which class
>   template argument deduction was performed. Each such notional
>   constructor is considered to be explicit if the function or function
>   template was generated from a constructor or *deduction-guide* that
>   was declared `explicit`. All such notional constructors are considered
>   to be public members of the hypothetical class type.

The hypothetical class type looks like:

```
class __hypothetical {
public:
  // ...

  // #1
  template<class InputIterator,
           class Compare = less<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>,
           class Allocator = allocator<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>>
  __hypothetical(InputIterator, InputIterator,
                 Compare = Compare(), Allocator = Allocator())
    -> set<typename iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type, Compare, Allocator>;

  // #2
  template<class Key, class Compare = less<Key>, class Allocator = allocator<Key>>
  __hypothetical(initializer_list<Key>, Compare = Compare(), Allocator = Allocator())
    -> set<Key, Compare, Allocator>;

  // ...
};
```

---

For the declaration of `s2`,

```
std::set s2 {a.begin(), a.end()};
```

The overload resolution is performed as if in

```
__hypothetical __hyp{a.begin(), a.end()}; // braces
```

Thus, [[over.match.list]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list) comes in.

> [...] overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the *initializer-list constructors* ([dcl.init.list]) of the class `T` and the argument list
>     consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
> - [...]

Constructor #2 is an *initializer-list constructor*. Function template argument deduction gives

```
Key = std::array<int>::iterator
```

So the deduced type of `s2` is

```
std::set<std::array<int>::iterator>
```

The declaration of `s2` is equivalent to

```
std::set<std::array<int>::iterator> s2 {a.begin(), a.end()};
```

Therefore, `s2` is a set of iterators that consists of two elements: `a.begin()` and `a.end()`. In your case, `std::array<int>::iterator` is probably `int*`, and `a.begin()` and `a.end()` happen to be serialized as `0x7ffecf9d12e0` and `0x7ffecf9d12f0`, respectively.

---

For `s3`, overload resolution is performed as if in

```
__hypothetical __hyp(a.begin(), a.end()); // parentheses
```

That's *direct-initialization*, and is under the scope of [[pver.match.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.ctor). The `initializer_list` constructor is irrelevant, and the Constructor #1 is selected instead. Function template argument deduction gives

```
InputIterator = std::array<int>::iterator
```

So the deduced type of `s3` is

```
set<iterator_traits<std::array<int>::iterator>::value_type>
```

Which is `set<int>`. Therefore, the declaration of `s3` is equivalent to

```
std::set<int> s3 (a.begin(), a.end());
```

`s3` is a set of `int`s that is initialized from the range `[a.begin(), a.end())` — four elements `1, 2, 3, 4`, which explains the output.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list and http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct